# In Perl, how can I determine if a subroutine was invoked as a method?

Tags: perl, methods

Is there a way to determine whether a subroutine is invoked as a method (with @ISA probing) or as a plain subroutine?  Perhaps with some sort of extension module super-[caller()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html)?

For example, given

```
package Ad::Hoc;

sub func() { ... }
```

How can `func()` discriminate between the following two invocations:

```
Ad::Hoc->func;            # or $obj->func

Ad::Hoc::func('Ad::Hoc'); # or func($obj)
```

(I know, the desire to do this is a *Likely Indication of Poor Design™*.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See if [Devel::Caller](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Caller) helps. I changed the code to invoke `func` on an object and it seems to work on my Mac with `perl` 5.14.3 (and 5.24.0):

> `called_as_method($level)`
>
> `called_as_method returns` true if the subroutine at `$level` was called as a method.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

package Ad::Hoc;
use strict; use warnings;

use Devel::Caller qw( called_as_method );

sub func {
    printf "%s\n", called_as_method(0) ? 'method' : 'function';
    return;
}

package main;
use strict; use warnings;

Ad::Hoc->func;
Ad::Hoc::func();
```

Output:

```
method
function
```

Comment: But you only need to use that if the method accepts a variable number of arguments. Otherwise, you can simply check the size of `@_`.

Comment: +1 very promising.  I get a fatal "pushmark or pad" error if I try `$blessed->func` with `called_as_method()` (5.18.0, PadWalker-1.96, D::Caller-2.06), but the "package method" invocation works perfectly, as you illustrate above.

Comment: @ikegami, agreed.  This is technical curiosity spun out of a problem that probably shouldn't have been allowed in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

```
package Ad::Hoc;

sub foo {
    my $self = shift;
    if(ref($self) ne 'Ad::Hoc') {
        unshift @_, $self;
        undef $self;
    }

    if($self) {
        # I'm a method
    } else {
        # I'm a sub
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this discriminate Ad::Hoc->func from func('Ad::Hoc'), or $o->func() from func($o)?

Comment: @pilcrow, yes, for you're second case, I don't know. If you're writing that, maybe you should just pass an additional flag.

Comment: It's incorrect in both cases, I think.  It treats `P->m()` and `m("P")` as "subroutine" invocations (one is not), and `$o->m()` and `m($o)` as "method" invocations (one is not).

Comment: @kjprice: That would 'kinda work' only if you call it from an already blessed object; but using your code just as presented, if you call `Ad::Hoc->foo()`, it will fall in the "I'm a sub" block even when it was called as a method. Also, even if you have a blessed object, if you just call `Ad::Hoc::foo($blessed)`, it will fall in the "I'm a method" block even when it was called as a sub.