# Determining if a Perl function has been called as a method

Tags: perl

Is there a way to tell if my Perl function has been called as `Package->method($a)` as opposed to `Package::method('Package', $a)`?

Comment: I think I want to say no, you can't. But I'm not sure I could prove it. My question would be - why do you need to know this? There may be a better way to accomplish that goal.

Comment: I think we've had a similar question a few weeks back. I remember something vaguely, including a similar clarification question @Sobrique.

Comment: Sorry, I can no longer mark this as a duplicate because I thought I picked the wrong one before, but this question is answered: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18217865/100754

Comment: @SinanÜnür that's the one I thought. I hammered it.